# In Swift, what is the best way to assign two arrays to key/value of a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, swift

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
let myKeys = ["one", "two", "three"]
let myValues = ["1",  "2", "3"]
```

and empty dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
```

What is the best way to assign `myKeys` and `myValues` as keys and values, respectively, of `myDictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my knowledge, this is the way to assign values/keys for your dictionary:

```
let count = myKeys.count
let count2 = myValues.count
if (count == count2) {
    for index in 0..count {
        myDictionary.updateValue(myValues[index], forKey:myKeys[index])
    }
}
```

Edit: Swift 2

```
let count = myKeys.count
let count2 = myValues.count
if (count == count2) {
    for index in 0 ..< count {
        myDictionary.updateValue(myValues[index], forKey:myKeys[index])
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want `0..count`?

Comment: but now it only goes from 0 to count-2.